# Python Speed Violation Calculator throwing back TypeError error

Tags: python, integer, typeerror

I'm having some issues, whilst debugging a program that I am designing to take in integer user inputs for a speed limit and a vehicle's speed, before my `violationCalculator` calculates by how much the user was speeding.

I am getting a `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'int'`, which is referencing `speedExcess = driverSpeed - designatedLimit`, held with `violationCalculator`
.

I am having issues identifying where I have gone wrong and would appreciate some guidance -

```
def speedLimit():
    designatedLimit = int(input("Please enter the designated speed limit: "))
    while designatedLimit not in range(20, 70):
        print("Invalid entry: please enter a valid speed limit (20-70)")
        designatedLimit = int(input("Please enter the designated speed limit: "))
    return designatedLimit

def vehicleSpeed(designatedLimit):
    driverSpeed = int(input("Please enter the vehicle's speed: "))
    while driverSpeed <= designatedLimit:
        print("You were not speeding!")
        driverSpeed = int(input("Please enter a valid vehicle speed: "))
        return driverSpeed

def violationCalculator(designatedLimit, driverSpeed):
    speedExcess = driverSpeed - designatedLimit
    return speedExcess

def main():
    welcomeSplash()
    designatedLimit = speedLimit()
    driverSpeed = vehicleSpeed(designatedLimit)
    speedExcess = violationCalculator(designatedLimit, driverSpeed)
    print("If you were travelling at", driverSpeed, "in a", designatedLimit, 
    "zone, then you were over the designated speed limit by", speedExcess)
main()
```

Comment: Hint: Consider what `vehicleSpeed` returns if the first `driverSpeed <= designatedLimit` test fails.

Comment: Thank you @PM2Ring - I don't know how I missed this, especially with a identical intention profile for `speedLimit`.

Comment: Sandeep has given the game away. ;) Now see if you can re-write `vehicleSpeed` so that it doesn't repeat `driverSpeed = int(input("Please enter the vehicle's speed: "))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just indentation problem . You are not returning anything sometimes since return is inside while

```
def vehicleSpeed(designatedLimit):
    driverSpeed = int(input("Please enter the vehicle's speed: "))
    while driverSpeed <= designatedLimit:
        print("You were not speeding!")
        driverSpeed = int(input("Please enter a valid vehicle speed: "))
    return driverSpeed
```

Check now

Comment: Thank you Sandeep!

Comment: I am glad that it helped. Please updated post as per https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Will do - I was just waiting for the time to elapse, so I can mark as answered :)